# firebase order by child time when time is firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I try to get all data from ideas that their "time" value is greater than 1, and limit it to 20 values.

but my query return null:

```
var ref = getRef(["ideas"]);
  ref.orderByChild("time").startAt("1").limitToLast(20).once("value", function(snapshot) {
 var _data = snapshot.val();
})
```

my "ideas" db look like this :

[image]

what am I missing? thanks

Comment: Try not using startAt() and limitToLast() together, it causes unexpected behaviuor , here( https://howtofirebase.com/collection-queries-with-firebase-b95a0193745d ) is a good explaination of why with good example

Comment: the same issue with this:  
    ref.orderByChild("time").startAt("1").once("value", ..

Comment: why pass a string "1" in startAt try with just number startAt(1)

Comment: you are right! I don't sure why I thought it should be string. many thanks

Comment: happy that you problem is solved....happy coding